# Size, resolution and quality recommendation for images

Tags: css, image

I'm looking for good articles around image resolutions, size and quality for web pages, especially around how this affects web sites currently.

I'm working on a web site for a client, and as an honour graduate in arts and design, the client is persistent that her 7mb - 10mb images are sufficient for her web site, totalling in at almost 400mb. I've tried arguing bandwidth limitations and performance but these are not holding ground.

The standard for images are at 72dpi, no larger than your standard screen resolution (1024x768) and above 1mb in size (which is already too large in my opinion). my argument is that loading 7mb+ files into a gallery on page load will seriously hinder the users experience if they have to wait a long period of time for 7 - 10 images to first get streamed into cache before the page is loaded, and even testing this with lazy loading plug-ins (we don't want to go flash) and late-loading has performance penalties.

Does anyone on here have any recommendation around image size, resolution and quality? We don't want to loose the HD quality of the images when users navigate the gallery (obviously we'll have to thumbnail them first)?

Comment: Have you research the 'save for web' functionality in Photoshop? Using 'save for web' at 80% quality in jpg format will generally give you good results. If your entire web page is larger than 1.5 MB -- you will have performance issues. I suspect some people would say that it shouldn't be over .5 mb.

Comment: Only big brands sites have the privilege of using elephant size imgs, because they CAN. There are usability issues here, websites are supposed to be clear (and beautiful, of course) because their aim is to communicate. I'd suggest you talk to your client. You are the professional, so you know what's right. For reasons you can ask in http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have read guidelines before (when we still used  1Mbps connections or less) and have been following these until now:

- high resolution images should not be bigger than 1.5 - 2MB. making it this big is like bigger than the webpage contents itself. try checking http://deviantart.com on how they place big photos in their site and check the image properties using the EXIF if any
- dimensions should be enough to be viewable in the browser (and avoid scrolling)
- compression is to be tested. it's a case to case basis, no setting is the same for everyone. high quality, high compression without visible quality loss is a practice in web design.
- JPEG is best for images, PNG for the layout and GIF for icons.
- try loading images in the background when the browser is idle using javascript. that way, they are in the cache before the user knows it.
- more on the webpage design, avoid using heavy graphics on the site itself, making the site fast so we only wait for the image.

Answer (score 1):

If you really boil it down you don't have a choice.

You are talking about HUGE file sizes which are not realistic.

You need to download a smaller version. After that you can subsequently download versions with increased quality or offer the full image with an onmouseover or click.

Answer (score 1):

Some general guidelines:

- Thumbnails (of course)
- Offer multiple image sizes (small, medium, large). While I understand the UX implications of giant images, some people **do** have fast connections and large displays and/or will be willing to wait for a high-resolution version. *But it shouldn't be the only option.*
- Try different compression levels to see what works best for different sizes. Using one compression level across the board doesn't always work. Again (depending on the source material), there may be a need for near-lossless compression at the high end. For example, images for print, CAD drawings with fine detail, etc.
- Use sequential loading techniques if applicable. For example, if you have ten images to load (optimized or not), make sure that the first visible one is the first one actually requested from the server.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes down to it, your client is under the impression that asking to shrink her image represents a 'compromise' that only results in damaging the quality of the image the user receives.

The truth is, of course, that an 8-10MB image is so large that it would take most users many seconds to download, creating a horrible user experience that will increase bounce rates.

Show your client a **side-by-side demo** of her website loading a handful of web-optimized images, and show her a site loading 8-10MB images, then let her decide. Ultimately, your job as professional is to assist her in making good choices, but she's free to make bad ones if she insists upon it (it's her brand, money, and right).

Something else you can potentially do is detect the size of the window and load larger images if the user is on an ultra-high-resolution monitor or if the window appears to be especially large.

Best of luck!

Comment: Use the dev panel to throttle the network speed during the demo. Perhaps the "Slow/Fast 3G" would be more convincing. :)